# change size of a image that's being fetched

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i made a website where i fetch an image from an api, i added a class to the div where the image is being inserted. I try to style the div in css and it doesn't change.

How can i modify the size of the image?

here's the code:

html:

```
<div class='roverImageStyles' id="roverImage"></div>
```

javascript

```
async function getimages() {
  const response = await fetch(`https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?earth_date=${document.getElementById("dateUserInput").value}&api_key=rwX3pO8mONvdxngtstqSuNfwhrwMoGTy6clxqSnu`)
  const data = await response.json()
  console.log(data)
  console.log(data.photos[counter].img_src) 
document.getElementById('roverImage').innerHTML = 

`<img src="${data.photos[counter].img_src}" /></a>`


}
```

Comment: *I try to style the div in css and it doesn't change* - show what you have tried

Comment: Please provide your css also.

Comment: What do you want to do ? actually modify the size of the image by editing it ? or just display the image at the size you want ? If it's the latter you can use css for that

Comment: I want the image thats being fetched and inserted to be no bigger than a certain size. Heres the css: ```
.roverImageStyles{
    max-width: 500px;
    
}```

Comment: you didn't add the opening anchor `a` tag into the `innerHTML` statement, add an opening anchor `<a>` tag and also add a class to `img` tag, then style it the way you want. `<a><img class="roverImage" src="${data.photos[counter].img_src}" /></a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the image to fill the size of the container. Add the following to your CSS

```
.nasaImage {max-width:100%}
```

and add the following to your JS

```
<img class="nasaImage" src="${data.photos[counter].img_src}" />
```